# calling ng-click function from an external script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am working on a chrome extension that can automate a form filling. So the form which i am filling has a next button attached to it that has a ng-click attribute "forward()" like this-

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{disabled: !showNext()}" ng-click="forward()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg default pull-right" style="font-size: 18px;">Next <i class="fa fa-chevron-right white-color"></i></button>
```

I tried calling `angular.element($('button.pull-right')).scope().forward()` or `$('button.pull-right').scope().forward()` and the function executes but the view doesnt get updated. I know i can do `$('button.pull-right'.click()` and that works but actually i am in need of bypassing the click event, for that i need to bind the click to my external script funciton(which i will inject into page through my extension) and then from my script call the `forward()` function.

I had a lot of time googling this but none worked out for me. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're reaching into Angular from outside of its context it will not notice that you've done so unless you tell it about it. You do that by using `$apply`.

Try this:

```
angular.element($('button.pull-right')).scope().$apply(function() {
    angular.element($('button.pull-right')).scope().forward();
});
```